# ViewPager dynamic width height

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

i'm trying to position indicator below view pager the problem is that i'm using layout_height (harcoded value 474dp) is possible to use dynamic width height in order to position indicator below view pager

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#dddddd">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#dddddd">


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/pager"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="274dp"
  android:layout_below="@+id/title"
  android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<CirclePageIndicator android:id="@+id/indicator"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/pager"
    app:pageColor="#858585"
    app:fillColor="#f19201" />

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: so if height is fixed then indicator isnt visible?

Comment: i dont want to use fixed height for view pager because this it will not work in many devices i want to use wrap_content but with this ViewPager is invisible

Comment: ok thanks but if i'm using a TextView in top of linear view breaks the width of view pager

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a`RelativeLayout` inside a scrollview it will never work, replace or wrap it with a   `LinearLayout`

Answer (score 0):

Use LinearLayout with weight property :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#dddddd"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.pockee.views.CirclePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        app:pageColor="#858585"
        app:fillColor="#f19201" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: with height 0dp image is invisible